# Using /was or /have been

Tags: grammar

I'm confused in using this sentence .

> I .... very busy last week

should I use

```
1 - I have been very busy last week
2-  I was very busy last week
3-  I has been very busy last week
```

I think the right is 2 or 3 ? 
Because its in the past so i should use `was` or `has been`

Comment: Personally, I would use 2. Number 3 is grammatically incorrect ("I has" should be "I have"). And number 1 should be "I have been very busy *in* the last week".

Comment: Thanks this helpful I didn't notice number 3 and number 1 maybe it required more practice to see examples similar , btw you can put this as an answer for my question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use 2. It is simple past tense.

Number 3 is grammatically incorrect ("I has" should be "I have"). (See http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-have.html for conjugations of "have").

Number 1 should be "I have been very busy *in the* last week" or "I have been very busy *this* last week". This is present perfect tense. You can use either Simple Past or Present Perfect depending on the context. This site: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_perfect.htm#perfect advises:

> The choice between Present Perfect and Simple Past is often determined by the adverbial accompanying the verb. With adverbs referring to a period gone by, we would use the simple past:
>   I studied all night/yesterday/on Wednesday.
>   With adverbs beginning in the past and going up to present, we would use the present perfect:
>   I have studied up to now/lately/already.
>   An adverbial time-marker such as "today, this month," or "for an hour" can take either the simple past or present perfect:
>   I worked/have worked hard today.
>   We tend to use the Present Perfect when reporting or announcing an event of the recent past:
>   The company's current CEO has lied repeatedly to her employees.
>   But we tend to use the Simple Past when reporting or announcing events of the finished, more distant past:
>   Washington encouraged his troops.
>   Because the time limits for Present Perfect are relatively elastic (stretching up to the present), it is somewhat less definite than the Simple Past:
>   Brett has worked with some of the best chefs of Europe [in the course of his long and continuing career].
>   Brett worked with Chef Pierre LeGout [when he lived in Paris].
>   (Notice how the topic of Brett's work is narrowed down as we move from Present Perfect to Simple Past.)